# Cassandra lightweight transactions

Tags: java, sql, cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job counts "application" events coming from a Kafka broker. I have a keyed window stream and, for each window, I count the number of events (I have 5-minutes windows). Finally I push the aggregated data into Cassandra with Cassandra Sink connector.

| application | window_start | window_end | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | **15** |
| app2 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | 23 |

I also handle late events with side-outputs. So, when a late event arrives I have this situation:

|     app1   |    2022-03-21 15:00:00   |   2022-03-21 15:05:00    |   1   |

The expected output must be:

| application | window_start | window_end | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | **16** |
| app2 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | 23 |

But it is:

| application | window_start | window_end | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | 1 |
| app2 | 2022-03-21 15:00:00 | 2022-03-21 15:05:00 | 23 |

This because Cassandra uses UPSERT.
With a SQL database (es. PostgreSQL) I can handle this problem:

"***INSERT INTO table(window_start, window_end, application, count) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (window_start, window_end, event_name, application) DO UPDATE SET count=EXCLUDED.count + table.count;***"

Is it possible to make this kind of query with Cassandra, or this is a limitation?

Remember I'm using Apache Flink and Cassandra as Sink and Java is my programming language.

Thanks!